4-Leds simple VU meter
I'm trying to build that circuit that is supposed to measure audio levels.
It's powered with +12V. It doesn't work when a line level audio, or even when a 2Hz square wave up to 10V from a signal generator is applied. The transistor is a NPN 2N3904. I'm not sure what input level is expected. I'd like it to work with a audio line level input. Would the led color even make a difference?
Sources:
https://youtu.be/OMeKERW1E60?si=EJKBvzdEH5WiXtGX&t=954
https://www.ericasynths.lv/media/COMPRESSOR_MANUAL.pdf


Could you measure the DC voltage across the second capacitor while the input was connected to the square wave? What was the source impedance?

4k7 resistors are too high and frequency is too low.

are you sure you mean 2Hz? not 2kHz or something? 2Hz is slowly varying DC, not in the audio band. You cannot hear it. Also, what are those upward pointing triangles connected to?

You can test by lowering the 33k  resistor values at the base of the transistors to increase the sensitivity of the circuit, allowing lower input voltages to turn on the LEDs. Here is an Arduino-based VU-meter design. You can try this too: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/DIY_Analog_VU_meter_with_Arduino_peak_meter_1ca2527f.html

First, let's fix the circuit to something workable:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The LED's don't really matter if your using the standard cheap indicator variety. Your first problem is your circuit was powered by ground, and referenced to another ground. Power the circuit with 5V to 9V. Yo can go higher (12V or 24V) by increasing the values of R1 to R4 based on the LED Vd and current.
Your next problem is the circuit will never work with 2Hz. And you don't need it to - 2Hz signals are outside the audio domain.
The secondary problem, both your circuit and my circuit will be a relatively low input impedance. This may be a problem from the pre-amp driving this circuitry so the signal might be severely compromised. However, if you have a strong preamp, this won't be a problem. If the loading is a problem, additional amplification/impedance matching on the input will correct this.
The last problem was the resistor values were in the wrong order. You need them to be approximately logogrammatically increasing in value to get the proper response.
R9 - R12 will tailor the sharpness/sensitivity of the circuit.
Keep in mind, this is very basic, low-performing circuit. There are much better solutions to do what you are trying to do.

Thank you very much, I will try this tonight and let you know.

I've tried your circuit at 5V, I use my Apogee headphones output where I measure 2V PP, but it doesn't work. I get the led blinking when i disconnect their emitters from the Ground, otherwise nothing. What am I doing wrong?

@brunobhr your signal is too low. The simplest thing you can try would be adding another 3904 transistor across the lowest transistor in Darlington configuration. No need to add one to the other 3 levels until you get the lowest level to flicker. If that works, you can do the same thing for all the levels. The fundamental issue is you don't have enough gain.

Or, one other thing you can do is add a resistor from 5V power to the top of C1 to introduce some bias. The value should be selected so that Vbe of Q4 amounts to around 500mV in the quiescent state.

Or, increase C2. It's hard to say specifically what to change - I didn't simulate or calculate this circuit. This all becomes trivial if you can take measurements with an oscilloscope and/or DMM.

I can push the soundcard up to 8V PP, which I find awfully high, but might me because it doesn't really have a load. Still nothing. I don't really understand your other comments like 'on top of C1'..it all might be trivial for you, but not for me, I'm just a small-time hobbyist..This seemed to be a good design from the demo video where it works perfectly, but now seems to get overly difficult..

Also, the leds should blink from left to right, with Led 1 on the left and Led 4 on the right, so I'm not sure about them being in the right order in your schematics. I was just trying the simplest way to get some indications on levels on an audio effect module.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The most bottom led needs about 8V across the right capacitor to glow. So consider the input amplitude to be about 5V at least.
The 2Hz is too low frequency for 1u5 caps. This circuit could work at >100Hz.

Increasing the capacitors to 1000uF and simulating it using 1N4148 diodes for the input voltage doubler, I get approximate thresholds of 1.5/2.5/4/5.5V peak, so RMS of about 1V/2V/3V/4V with 2Hz sine wave input.


You can find an integrated solution for VU meter amplitude response (logarithmic) on the LM3915 datasheet. The LM3914 is the equivalent for linear response. They also show precision rectifier circuits more suitable for low input voltage levels than the simple diode voltage doubler. TI has discontinued the LM3915, however an equivalent is still being manufactured by at least one Chinese manufacturer (Shenzhen HTC Semi).

Sorry for the late response. I tried your schematics with my audio card from 0 to 3.5V PP, and could not even get one led blinking. I know there are plenty of other solutions, but I wanted something simple, just like in the sources I posted. Unfortunately it seems very hard to reproduce for some reason. Thanks anyway.

Also, a 5V 2HZ sinewave just lights up the two first leds, which then stay on.
